# Compiling Objective-C project on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: objective-c, linux, ubuntu, compilation

How to make an Objective-C project work on Ubuntu?

My files are:

*Fraction.h*

```
    #import <Foundation/NSObject.h>

    @interface Fraction: NSObject {
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
    }

    -(void) print;
    -(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
    -(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
    -(int) numerator;
    -(int) denominator;
    @end
```

*Fraction.m*

```
    #import "Fraction.h"
    #import <stdio.h>

    @implementation Fraction
    -(void) print {
        printf( "%i/%i", numerator, denominator );
    }

    -(void) setNumerator: (int) n {
        numerator = n;
    }

    -(void) setDenominator: (int) d {
        denominator = d;
    }

    -(int) denominator {
        return denominator;
    }

    -(int) numerator {
        return numerator;
    }
    @end
```

main.m

```
    #import <stdio.h>
    #import "Fraction.h"

    int main( int argc, const char *argv[] ) {
        // create a new instance
        Fraction *frac = [[Fraction alloc] init];

        // set the values
        [frac setNumerator: 1];
        [frac setDenominator: 3];

        // print it
        printf( "The fraction is: " );
        [frac print];
        printf( "\n" );

        // free memory
        [frac release];

        return 0;
    }
```

I've tried two approaches to compile it:

1. Pure gcc:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install gobjc gnustep gnustep-devel
   $ gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -o main main.m -lobjc -lgnustep-base
   /tmp/ccIQKhfH.o:(.data.rel+0x0): undefined reference to `__objc_class_name_Fraction'
   ```
2. I created a GNUmakefile Makefile:

   ```
   include ${GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES}/common.make

   TOOL_NAME = main
   main_OBJC_FILES = main.m

   include ${GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES}/tool.make
   ```

   ... and ran:

   ```
   $ source /usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh
   $ make
   Making all for tool main...
    Linking tool main ...
   ./obj/main.o:(.data.rel+0x0): undefined reference to `__objc_class_name_Fraction'
   ```

So in both cases compiler gets stuck at

```
    undefined reference to `__objc_class_name_Fraction'
```

Do you have and idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's right. In both cases you did not include `Fraction.m` in your list of files to be compiled, so it can't find the implementation of the class `Fraction`

From the comment, this command works

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -o main *.m -lobjc -lgnustep-base
```

Comment: actually it i a linker error. newacct is right.

Im not sure about the <Foundation/NSObject.h> include, too. I think this only provided on MacOS not in GNUStep.

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert at writing the make files like that, I find simply typing the following works on ubuntu quite well:

```
gcc -I /usr/include/GNUstep/ -I /usr/include/mysql -L /usr/lib/GNUstep/\
    -lgnustep-base -lmysqlclient\
    -g -ggdb\
    -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -o test *.m
```

I am using it on this project:

http://github.com/uptecs/SmsgateDelivery/

If the above GCC command does not work you have not installed enough packages, use apt-cache to search for more gcc and objective c packages to install (I just installed more packages that looked relevant at random until it worked)

Answer (score 3):

**the make file:**

```
include ${GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES}/common.make

APP_NAME=Fraction
Fraction_HEADERS = Fraction.h
Fraction_OBJC_FILES = main.m Fraction.m


include ${GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES}/application.make
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach I just got working was (in Ubuntu, which is closely related to Debian):

- Use Synaptic to install all likely-looking GnuStep packages;
- Source ( `.` ) the GnuStep startup script, `/usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh` (this can go into `.profile` or `.bashrc` or something so you don't have to do it manually every time)
- Create a `GNUmakefile` according to the instructions in [A First Tool](http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/node2.html)

This allowed me to successfully build command line programs.

Answer (score 2):

Add Fraction.m in make file,

---

include ${GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES}/common.make

TOOL_NAME = main

main_OBJC_FILES = main.m **Fraction.m**

include ${GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES}/tool.make

---

and then make ^^

Answer (score 2):

Just add Fraction.m in main.m instead to add Fraction.h in main.m. And this will work. The following is the main.m file i used :

```
#import <stdio.h>  
#import "Fraction.m"

int main( int argc, const char *argv[] ) {  
    //create a new instance  
    Fraction *frac = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    //set the values 
    [frac setNumerator: 1];
    [frac setDenominator: 3];

    //print it
    printf("The fraction is : ");
    [frac print];
    printf("\n");

    //free memory
    [frac release];

    return 0;
}
```